# What event activates the keyboard in mobile safari

Tags: iphone, html, mobile, mobile-safari, cordova

So the focus event causes the soft keyboard to come up for input fields. Im trying to find a way to stop this occuring. The reason is, as some of you may know, a click event has a 300ms delay before anything happens.

To get around this, we have implemented Googles FastButton http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons.html its working good after a minor tweak to also prevent a second mousedown, but if we click on a button and go to a second page that also has a input textfield, the keyboard still pops up.

I've tried preventing the touchend, mousedown, mouseend, click, firing again, and that helps it by not having the flashing cursor on the textfield but the keyboard is still there. If i blur the field you still see the keyboard popping up then disapparing which is not acceptable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... have you considered disabling the fields with `disabled="disabled"` while loading, and only then enabling them? It might let you get around the initial focused state that launches the keyboard, so that you can blur first, then enable?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, i have tried setting the field to read only and resetting it 300ms later. But thats a last approach, ideally i would like to be able to prevent whatever action is causing the keyboard to show up

Comment: Any chance of a test URL or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) test case that demonstrates this? I am a bit stumped as to why the input is getting focus in the first place.

Comment: its because the click event is firing twice, if you refer her:  http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons.html. We are activating the button press event on touch start, then 300ms later the standard safari click initiates which is firing after our 2nd page has loaded

Comment: Ah... I totally misunderstood the problem. The issue is the way the ghost-click-buster works. It listens in capture mode for the secondary click in 300ms. The problem is that all frameworks clean up their listeners at onunload to prevent leaks, so when you change URL, the buster is immediately torn down and is not there to bust, but the click has already entered the queue. The solution I think is to prevent default **only** on this particular touch listener that causes a page switch. This will prevent the ghost click from ever being born, and thus no keyboard.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, the buster is not torn down, its attached at the document level. Its working well, and correctly busts the second click, if the second click is on a button, list, hyperlink etc. Its just that if its on an input field, it correctly busts it so that there is no cursor on the input field but the soft keyboard still pops up.